# Need Migration steps for Angular js to Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to migrate my angular js (1.5) to angular 8. I have gone through various links and found some approaches like going for incremental migration like angular js to angular 2, and then angular 4,5,and so on.

My question is that, Is there a way to do it automatically / manually? or Do we have any checklist/cookbook to migrate?

Please provide some tips to identify the approach and help in this migration